# What else can you call a JSON object - is it hash map? - conceptual questions

Tags: javascript, json, hashmap

One thing bothered me quite a bit when learning Javascript while trying to incorporate CS concepts - what exactly is JSON? I heard of people calling it associative arrays, key value pair objects, Javascript Objects.

Correct me if I'm wrong - I know in Java Hash Maps are more or less key value pairs. Since I feel like JSON shares a lot of properties with that, can I safely call JSON objects hash maps without sounding like an idiot in interviews?

Thanks

Comment: Could you care to explain why?

Comment: For the same reason you cannot call it a honeymoon cruise, though it carries many pairs as well.

Comment: If you have nothing useful to say please keep it to yourself.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON - For more understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You could call it a lightweight human readable structured text document. Human readable like xml, but not as verbose hence lightweight. You might compare it to other data encoding mechanisms like protocol buffers, yaml or (the previously mentioned) XML.

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer I was more or less looking for. I guess I need read more into Hash maps.

Answer (score 0):

JSON - JavaScript Object Notation

Data objects consisting of attribute-value pairs.